# Sonarqube catastrophic backtracking with regex that I use

Tags: javascript, regex, sonarqube

So in one of my views I am using regex which is looking like that:

`RegExp('^(?!(.|\n)*{\/?.+})(.|\n)*$')`

ANd sonarlint is giving me a warning about catastrophic backtracking and should make sure that I should use a regex that cannot lead to denial of service.
From what I have read it mostly happens on regexes that are not too complex and are using a lot of "any" character calls like . or +

This is the first time for me to see a security hotspot like this, should I try to rewrite this regex or is it complex enough so it won't trigger catastrophic backtracking

Comment: Never use `(.|\n)*`. This construct is a performance killer. All you need is a `[^]` construct to match any char. You regex is basically `/^(?![^]*{[^}]*})[^]*$/` and probably a ``/^(?![^]*{[^}]*})/`` is enough. But all you need is `if !(/{[^}]*}/.test(text)) { return true; }`

Comment: Isn't here a small mistake where you have put additional } in [^}]
and should be like this? ```/^(?![^]*{[^]*})[^]*$/```

Comment: No, it is on purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of points to note here:

- The `(.|\n)*` construct causes very poor performance due to excessive backtracking. See ["*Why `(?:\s|.)*` is a bad pattern to match any character including line breaks*"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEobSs-ZCSE) YouTube video with detailed explanation of why this is a very bad pattern. All you need is a `[^]` construct to match any chars.
- You regex is basically `/^(?![^]*{[^}]*})[^]*$/`, or even `/^(?![^]*{[^}]*})/` since JavaScript regex functions do not require full string match. All you need here is to actually use `{[^}]*}` pattern and negate the result with `!`.

So you can use

```js
if !(/{[^}]*}/.test(text)) {
    return true;
}
```

where `{[^}]*}` matches a `{`, then any zero or more chars other than `}` and then a `}` char.